# .htaccess redirect from a URL to the site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to set up the redirect, which would bring any user from

`http://vps.domain.com/~access/` (and subfolders, such as `/~access/user` etc.)

to

`http://www.example.com`

What's the Rewrite rule I have to use?

Will that one work?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vps.domain.com/~access/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can place this rule in `~access/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vps\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vps\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/~access/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```